# I am using pdf js library for representing pdf files by pdf flipbook library but search is not working here

Tags: javascript, pdf.js

I am using https://github.com/erayakartuna/pdf-flipbook, I want to implement search functionality for this, I did check out some other solution on stackoverflow but looks like viewer.js is customized in this library.
I would like to get any help possible on this issue.

It does finds the matches as the count shows that but it does not goes to the page when I click on next match button.

Thanks.

Previous
              
              
              
                Next

```
      <div id="findbarOptionsOneContainer">
        <input type="checkbox" id="findHighlightAll" class="toolbarField" tabindex="94">
        <label for="findHighlightAll" class="toolbarLabel" data-l10n-id="find_highlight">Highlight all</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="findMatchCase" class="toolbarField" tabindex="95">
        <label for="findMatchCase" class="toolbarLabel" data-l10n-id="find_match_case_label">Match case</label>
      </div>
      <div id="findbarOptionsTwoContainer">
        <input type="checkbox" id="findEntireWord" class="toolbarField" tabindex="96">
        <label for="findEntireWord" class="toolbarLabel" data-l10n-id="find_entire_word_label">Whole words</label>
        <span id="findResultsCount" class="toolbarLabel hidden"></span>
      </div>

      <div id="findbarMessageContainer">
        <span id="findMsg" class="toolbarLabel"></span>
      </div>
    </div>  <!-- findbar -->
```